# win32com.client error

Tags: win32com

When using win32com, something puzzled my.

```
>>> import win32com
>>> w=win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    w=win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'client'
```

what's wrong?

Answer (score 21):

win32com.client is a module in the win32com package you need to import the actual module.

```
import win32com.client 

w = win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application')
```

Comment: It would help if you told what the error is. Wit h this information alone you can not be helped further. So you need to either expand over ask another question. However this is not a  forum but a live FAQ you should post a new question. However this is the answer to the question asked.